# Java Extracting class information from a generic type

Tags: java, generics

How can I assign value to `Class<T>` - without having to pass it explicitly? I know about type erasure story. But I am wondering: doesn't Java compiler see `Class<T> c` and realize that I am talking about `<T>`, shouldn't I be able to use this variable without initialization! OR shouldn't it be automatically initialized as a primitive. Why wasn't it designed that way?

```
static class D<T> {
    T t;
    Class<T> c;

    D(T t) {
        this.t = t;
        method(t.getClass()); // no error!
        c = t.getClass(); // error!
    }

    void q() {
        method(c); // no error at compile time
    }
}

static <K> void method(Class<K> clazz) {
}
```

Comment: o yeah, that worked. So it means that I actually don't need to pass Class<T> together with an object of T!

Comment: I am curious to know, who downvoted the question and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because getClass() is an method of the Object base class. That method returns a value of type "`Class <?>` ". So you cannot assign it to `Class<T>` without a type cast.